# PHP Email - Format spacing in Plain Text

Tags: php, email, format, alignment, spacing

I'm want to send php mail in plain text and i am NOT allowed to use html but I'm having issues with spacing. The output should look like this:

```
Item         Qty        Price
Whatever      1          5000USD
Whatever2     2            50USD

 Subtotal                5050USD
 Tax                       50USD

 TOTAL                   5100USD
```

Which is pretty difficult considering amounts and product names always vary so it ends up looking very messy. Since columns widths are always going to be different i would like to right-align the last column so everything looks aligned and clean. Is there any practical method to do this?

Thank you.

EDIT:

This is my current code:

```
function render($indent = "", InvoicePayment $payment = null)
{
    $prefix = (!is_null($payment) && !$payment->isFirst()) ? 'second' : 'first';
    $tm_added = is_null($payment) ? $this->tm_added : $payment->dattm;

    $newline = "\r\n";

    $price_width = max(mb_strlen(Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_total'}, $this->currency)), 8);

    $column_padding = 3;
    $column_title_max = 60;
    $column_title_min = 20;
    $column_qty = 15;
    $column_num = 3;
    $column_amount = $price_width;
    $space = str_repeat(' ', $column_padding);

    $max_length = 0;
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $max_length = max(mb_strlen(___($item->item_title)), $max_length);
    }

    $column_title = max(min($max_length, $column_title_max), $column_title_min);
    $row_width = $column_num + $column_padding +
                 $column_title + $column_padding +
                 $column_qty + $column_padding +
                 $column_amount + $column_padding;

    $column_total = $column_title +
                    $column_qty + $column_padding;
    $total_space = str_repeat(' ', $column_padding + $column_num + $column_padding);

    $border = $indent . str_repeat('-', $row_width) . "$newline";

    $out = $indent . ___("Invoice") . ' #' . $this->public_id . " / " . amDate($tm_added) . "$newline";
    $out .= $border;
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$space}%{$column_num}s{$space}%-{$column_title}s{$space}%{$column_qty}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline",
            " ", ___('Subscription/Product Title'), ___('Quantity'), ___('Unit Price'));
    $out .= $border;
    $num = 1;
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $title = explode("\n", $this->wordWrap(___($item->item_title), $column_title, "\n", true));
        $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$space}%{$column_num}s{$space}%-{$column_title}s{$space}%{$column_qty}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline",
            $num . '.', $title[0], $item->qty, Am_Currency::render($item->{$prefix . '_price'}, $this->currency));
        for ($i=1; $i<count($title); $i++)
            $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$space}%{$column_num}s{$space}%-{$column_title}s$newline", ' ', $title[$i]);
        $num++;
    }
    $out .= $border;
    if ($this->{$prefix . '_subtotal'} != $this->{$prefix . '_total'})
        $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Subtotal'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_subtotal'}, $this->currency));
    if ($this->{$prefix . '_discount'} > 0)
        $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Discount'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_discount'}, $this->currency));
    if ($this->{$prefix . '_shipping'} > 0)
        $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Shipping'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_shipping'}, $this->currency));
    if ($this->{$prefix . '_tax'} > 0)
        $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Tax'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_tax'}, $this->currency));
    $out .= $border;
    $out .= $newline;
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Total'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_total'}, $this->currency));
    if ($this->rebill_times) {
        $terms = explode("\n", $this->wordWrap(___($this->getTerms()), $row_width, "\n", true));
        foreach ($terms as $term_part)
            $out .= $indent . $term_part . $newline;
        $out .= $border;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spacing will never work as it will be very diffcult to manage your code.

Instead map those fields/values in a HTML table and set the border to 0 , also you should render your mail as HTML for the above things to work.

To do this.. go to `http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables` and generate the table as per you want , Click generate and you will get the HTML source code for it..

[image]

After that, you can paste those source on your email message , *Don't forget to set the border to 0.*  Render your mail headers to HTML , to send this as an HTML mail.

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Mail code grabbed from [PHP Manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Im not allowed to use html, if i was i had used html from the very beginning.

Comment: @CainNuke, Tell your boss or your team leader that HTML is really neccessary here :) , because it will be very hard to maintain code if you do with the manual spacing !

Comment: Hi, unfortunately its not about somebody's orders. The script itself is already made this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you give multiple spaces between two elements then HTML will only consider single space. You can use `&nbsp` for spacing. Another best way to do this is to write an HTML table for that.

Comment: I must do it in plain text, thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a table for this

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
     <td>Item</td>  <td>Qty</td>  <td>Price</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>Whatever1</td>  <td>1</td>  <td>5000USD</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>Whatever2</td>  <td>2</td>  <td>50USD</td>
  </tr>

  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

   <tr>
     <td>Subtotal</td>  <td>&nbsp;</td>  <td>5050USD</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>Tax</td>  <td>&nbsp;</td>  <td>50USD</td>
  </tr>

   <tr><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

   <tr>
     <td>Total</td>  <td>&nbsp;</td>  <td>5100USD</td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Comment: Im not allowed to use html, sorry.